# Why is my rotation matrix not working properly?

Tags: math, rust, rotation, linear-algebra

I've been working a bit on this simple rasterizer, but the cube I imported is not rotating properly. Here's a picture of the issue: [image]

I copied a rotation matrix from this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). Here's the rotation function:

```
    pub fn rotate(self, theta: f32, axis: Vec3) -> Obj {

        let u = Vec3::normalize(axis);
        
        let mut tempVec: Vec<Vec3> = vec![];

        let thetaCos = theta.cos();
        let thetaSin = theta.sin();

        for i in 0..self.vertices.len() {
        tempVec.push(Vec3::new( (thetaCos + u.x.powf(2.) * (1. - thetaCos))    * self.vertices[i].x + (u.x * u.y * (1. - thetaCos) - u.z * thetaSin) * self.vertices[i].y + (u.x * u.z * (1. - thetaCos) + u.y * thetaSin) * self.vertices[i].z,
                                (u.y * u.x * (1. - thetaCos) + u.z * thetaSin) * self.vertices[i].x + (thetaCos + u.y.powf(2.) * (1. - thetaCos))    * self.vertices[i].y + (u.y * u.z * (1. - thetaCos) - u.x * thetaSin) * self.vertices[i].z,
                                (u.z * u.x * (1. - thetaCos) - u.y * thetaSin) * self.vertices[i].x + (u.z * u.y * (1. - thetaCos) + u.x * thetaSin) * self.vertices[i].y + (thetaCos + u.z.powf(2.) * (1. - thetaCos))    * self.vertices[i].z));
        }
        return Obj { vertices: tempVec, faces: self.faces };

    }
```

And here's how it gets called in the main loop:

```
model = model.rotate(0.01 , Vec3::new(0.,1.,0.));
```

I'm really not sure what isn't working. I tried a different matrix and it failed even worse. Here's my projection code:

```
pub fn perspective(vec: Vec3, camPos: Vec3) -> Vec2 {

    let f = vec.z - camPos.z;

    let new_x = ((vec.x - camPos.x) * (f/vec.z)) + camPos.x;
    let new_y = ((vec.y - camPos.y) * (f/vec.z)) + camPos.y;

    return Vec2::new(new_x, new_y);

}
```

Comment: Looks like [Elite - the game](http://bbcmicro.co.uk/game.php?id=366) from the 80's

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add [tag:Rust] as a tag, and remove it from the title. Also does rust support matrices and matrix/vector operations? Finally, better cache the results of `sin()` and `cos()` so they don't get evaluated over and over again.

Comment: I checked your rotation function, which is indeed the Rodrigues rotation formula. And `u` is indeed normalized, which would be another pitfall. So something else is going on here. The [rotation matrix](https://i.imgur.com/rQiz4Ts.png) is what Wikipedia mentions.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Thanks for the tip on caching sin(theta) and cos(theta)! I wouldn't have thought to do that.

Comment: Have you tried rendering without rotating the mesh first. I think the problem is somewhere else and not in the `rotate()` function.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I have, and it seems to work (as per this image https://imgur.com/a/GfO8XpR). There might be an issue with my projection, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comments the issue is not with the rotation as the math checks out.

The issue should be with the projection.

Here is the geometry for the perspective projections. Below is a sketch from the side showing how *y* and *z* coordinates interact. Something similar happens between the *x* and *z* coordinates as well

[image: fig1]

Given a point **P** with `(x,y,z)` coordinates, you want to find point **Q** which is the projection on the model plane.

More specifically you need to find the distance **QC** and relate it as a ratio to the distance **AB**. This is because on screen the distance **AB** corresponds to the height **H** in pixels of your viewport.

So the vertical pixel count is

```
          y     L
py = H * --- * ---
         AB    L-z
```

where **L** is the distance to the camera/eye along the *z* axis.

Sometimes the model size **AB** isn't known, but instead the field of view (FOV) in degrees is. From trigonometry, we have `tan(fov/2*π/180) = AB/(2*L)` which simplifies the projection as such

```
                 1          y
py = H * -------------- *  ---
         tan(fov*π/360)    L-z
```

Typically the factor `f=H/tan(fov*π/360)` is pre-computed and the projection of point **P** is

```
px = f * (x/(L-z))
py = f * (y/(L-z))
```

Comment: Thanks to you, my spinning teapot is perfectly proportions.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being an issue with my perspective projection. This is the code that worked for me:

```
pub fn perspective(vec: Vec3, camPos: Vec3, fov: f32) -> Vec2 {

    let camDist = Vec3::length(camPos - vec);
    let pixel_x = fov*vec.x/(camDist-vec.z);
    let pixel_y = fov*vec.y/(camDist-vec.z);
    return Vec2::new(pixel_x, pixel_y);
}
```

Credit to @JohnAlexiou for the massive help.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. I have [done this many times](https://i.imgur.com/7gPTjHJ.png) in many languages. My projections are of the `pixel_x = f*x/(camDist - z)` and `pixel_y = f*y/(camDist - z)` form where the **z** axis points towards the camera.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou If you wouldn't mind, what exactly is camDist? I tried setting it to the camera's Z position, though that returned a suboptimal result.

Comment: `camDist` is the distance between the eye and the target. And the factor `f` depends on the field of view angle and the viewport size.